# Schedule rebuild of smart index

Tags: kentico

I have created a simple Smart search index locally (page crawler with simple analyser). When I manually trigger a rebuild, I'm able to find a page using a test keyword.. However, if I save the page with a new keyword, I don't see the change until I trigger the rebuild again. I can see several tasks listed under "Local tasks", but nothing happens when I click "process tasks". Is there a scheduled task somewhere else that I need to be running? I read elsewhere that it might be "Execute local search tasks" but that doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: A few questions: are you working on Kentico 12 MVC? Are you adding Keywords in Kentico standard Metadata fields or do you have a custom field in your page type?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the Smart search index task in the schedule tasks module.